# jQuery - Clear form field with .change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following jQuery code to switch div displays based on a change event tied to 3 radio buttons:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.change_form_fields = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $('div.form-item-payment-method input').each(function() {
        if (this.value != 'existing-bill') {
          $('div#' + this.value).css('display', 'none');
        }
      });

      $('div.form-item-payment-method input').change(function() {
        show_class = this.value;
        $('div.form-item-payment-method input').each(function() {
          if (this.value != show_class) {
            $('input#edit-' + this.value).val('');
            $('div#' + this.value).css('display', 'none');
          } else {
            $('div#' + this.value).css('display', 'block');
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
}(jQuery));
```

This works fine and dandy, but I want to add some more to it.

If a user selects a radio button, I want to blank/clear out the form fields in the other groups. Like the onload (.each), they have divs around the display content.

I tried using .attr and .val, but the form fields would not clear when selecting another radio button. What am I missing? jQuery 1.4x+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val('')` should do the trick, so there must be some other issue with either the selector, or the code not being run.

Comment: Thank you, I changed my js to do this before hiding divs: $('fieldset#edit-payment-information input[type=text], fieldset#edit-payment-information select').val('');

Answer (score 1):

Use the radio buttons change event that should help you.

```
$("input[type=radio][name=groupname]").change(function(){

     //Code the clear the form fields or other logic here.
});
```